# using calcOpticalFlowPyrLK() function in visual studio

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to to test the calcOpticalFlowPyrLK() int c++ in visual studio, but i had some problems during writing the code. I get the keypoints of my 2 images with the FAST algorithm.
Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
    Mat im1, im1gray, im2, im2gray;
    vector<KeyPoint> keypoints1;
    vector<KeyPoint> keypoints2;
    im1=imread("C:\\Users\\Dániel\\Desktop\\1.png", 1);
    im2=imread("C:\\Users\\Dániel\\Desktop\\2.png", 1);
    cvtColor(im1, im1gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    FAST(im1gray, keypoints1, 100, true);
    cvtColor(im2, im2gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    FAST(im2gray, keypoints2, 100, true);
    vector<char> status;
    vector<float> error;
    calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(im1, im2, keypoints1, keypoints2, status, error, Size(20,20), 1, cvTermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_ITER | CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 20, .3 ), 0, 0.0001);
```

My problem is that I get an error message (Unhandled exception at 0x74fc4b32 in KLT.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x008de7ac..) when I try to run the last command of the code. Can anyobody tell me what can the problem be? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`calcOpticalFlowPyrLK` works with `vector<Point2f>`, not with `vector<KeyPoint>`. You should convert keypoints array to array with coordinates:

```
vector<Point2f> pt1, pt2;
KeyPoint::convert(keypoints1, pt1);
KeyPoint::convert(keypoints2, pt2);
calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(im1, im2, pt1, pt2, status, error, Size(20,20), 1, cvTermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_ITER | CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 20, .3 ), 0, 0.0001);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now! The other thing was that I had to use vector<uchar>error instead of vector<char>error.